# Webpack recognize Angular 2 loadChildren and split into chunks?

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-2

I ran into a blog post where webpack apparently splits the code because of the way load children is set, which is pretty cool.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'dynamic',
    loadChildren: () => {
      return System.import('./dynamic.module').then((comp: any) => {
        return comp.default;
      });
    }
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: InlineComponent
  }
];
```

[http://blog.waffle.io/code-splitting-angular-2-webpack-2/][1]

What I would like to know is how the same thing could be done with a preloading strategy a la the below

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'dist', redirectTo: '/landing'},
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/landing', pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule'},
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules}) 
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
```

I'm preparing the router for an upgrade to a newer version and ran into this and thought it would be pretty awesome. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.